# Why does this function cause a memory leak?

Tags: java, mysql, memory

```
public void filterLogins() throws IOException, SQLException{
    for(int i = 0; i<200; ++i){
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(folder + String.format("\\data\\part-%05d", i)));
        long prev_id = 0;
        boolean contains = false;
        while(bufferedReader.ready()){ //very big file
            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            Login login = new Login(line);
            if ( login.userId == prev_id && !contains )
                continue;
            if ( samples.contains(login.userId) ){
                mysql.execute("INSERT INTO ..."); // i think it doesn't matter in this case
                contains = true;
            }else{
                contains = false;
            }
            prev_id = login.userId;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        System.out.println((double)i/2.0);
    }
}
```

This function works long time, because data is more big files. 2 hours ago this is crushess with OutOfMemory Exception

mysql is instance of

```
public class MySQLHandler {
private Connection connection = null;
MySQLHandler() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database", "root", "");
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
        System.out.println("Failed jdbc driver load.");
        throw e;
    }
}


public void close() throws SQLException{
       if ( connection != null)
           connection.close();
   }
   public boolean execute(String sql) throws SQLException{
       Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
       return statement.execute(sql);
   }
}
```

Login it is just class with data. (id, name, value, something else).

Comment: what is the type of the file, maybe there is another way to parse it ?

Comment: Certainly there are all sorts of ways to generate out-of-storage conditions with SQL and the like.

Comment: What class is the `mysql` object? (I'm wondering if it's something akin to a `PreparedStatement`)

Comment: what is mysql ? and what is samples ( is it string ?) . Also do the Login has reference with any other object / is it simple POJO ?

Comment: A profiler should be able to tell you what type of objects are on the heap, so you can watch that to see what's eating up all your memory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems, you are creating Statement each time and not closing the statement in your loop which will leak memory .
close the statement once execute is completed.

```
 public boolean execute(String sql) throws SQLException{
       Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
       return statement.execute(sql);
   }
```

Like

```
 public boolean execute(String sql) throws SQLException{
     Statement statement = null;
    try {
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        return statement.execute(sql);
    }finaly{
         if (statement != null) statement.close();
     }

UPDATE
```

As @Holger mentioned in comment, if you are using JDK 7 and higher then you can use [try-with-resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html) 
like below

```
public boolean execute(String sql) throws SQLException{
       try(Statement s=connection.createStatement()) {
          return s.execute(sql);
       }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think problem in it. But why the does not close automatically? In online docs "close() Releases this Statement object's database and JDBC resources immediately instead of waiting for this to happen when it is automatically closed."

Comment: @chubakur you welcome. It will close automatically when you close the connection. But you are not closing the connection in loop ( i believe you might keep live always . that is different problem). at least closing the statements will release the objects associate with that. As the online doc suggests " Release statement immediately once its done "

Comment: [`try(Statement s=connection.createStatement()) { return s.execute(sql); }`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the max heap size of your JVM
eg:

```
-Xms<size>        set initial Java heap size
-Xmx<size>        set maximum Java heap size
-Xss<size>        set java thread stack size

java -Xms16m -Xmx64m ClassName
```

Also optimzie your code and reuse variables and close/cleanup after use. For eg: Move these outside the loop:
BufferedReader bufferedReader, String line and Login login

```
public void filterLogins() throws IOException, SQLException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    long prev_id;
    boolean contains;
    String line;
    Login login;
    for(int i = 0; i<200; ++i){
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(folder + String.format("\\data\\part-%05d", i)));
        prev_id = 0;
        contains = false;
        while(bufferedReader.ready()){ //very big file
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
            login = new Login(line);
            if ( login.userId == prev_id && !contains )
                continue;
            if ( samples.contains(login.userId) ){
                mysql.execute("INSERT INTO ..."); // i think it doesn't matter in this case
                contains = true;
            }else{
                contains = false;
            }
            prev_id = login.userId;
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        System.out.println((double)i/2.0);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is truly a memory leak increasing the heap size won't help.  It would just delay the inevitable.

Comment: Moving variables outside the loop is going to make literally no difference in memory consumption. If anything, that could be an anti-optimization for readability and limiting scope

Comment: When you declare a variable of a primitive type, the compiler reserves sufficient room in memory to hold the largest acceptable value for the declared type and associates the variable name with that location. When you declare a variable of a reference type, sufficient room in memory is allocated to hold a reference.

Comment: But it all depends on the compiler whether it optimizes the byte code and the type of the variable, as mentioned above (primitive vs reference type). Usually memory wastage happens when people repeatedly initialize same variable with same value inside loop. There could be a performance improvement also if compiler doesn't optimize. It can also be argued that defining all variables together before use increases readability :)